# Is it possible to use gatling to test rsocket protocol over websocket?

Tags: spring, websocket, gatling, rsocket

I want to create performance test in **gatling** which check my server in spring. I use **rsocket** protocol(over **websocket**). I don't know how to **establish connection** and **send** any data through this protocol. Is gatling support it? If it isn't possible using gatling how can i simulate specific number of connection to my server. (maybe different library)

Server code

```
@Bean
public Mono<RSocketRequester> rSocketRequester(
        RSocketStrategies rSocketStrategies,
        RSocketProperties rSocketProps) {
    return RSocketRequester.builder()
            .rsocketStrategies(rSocketStrategies)
            .connectWebSocket(getURI(rSocketProps));
}
private URI getURI(RSocketProperties rSocketProps) {
    return URI.create(String.format("ws://localhost:%d%s",
            rSocketProps.getServer().getPort(), rSocketProps.getServer().getMappingPath()));
}
```

properties file:

```
spring.rsocket.server.port=8080
spring.rsocket.server.transport=websocket
spring.rsocket.server.mapping-path=/rsocket
```

Examples endpoints where i want to send message:

```
@ConnectMapping
void joinToGame(RSocketRequester rSocketRequester) {
  
}

@MessageMapping("exampleEndpoint")
public void disconnect() {
   
}
```

maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-rsocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```